# Bounding the total variation metric between Gaussian mixtures

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, it.information-theory, information-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with total variation metric $\delta$, fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathcal{P}'\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the metric subspace of all probability measures $\nu$ of the form
$$
\nu : =\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \nu(\mu_i,\Gamma_i),
$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i =1, \, 0\leq \alpha_i\leq 1$, $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $\Gamma_i$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Can $\delta(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ be bounded above in terms of the distance between the Euclidean distance between their parameters (i.e.: $\alpha_i,\mu_i, \Gamma_i$)?

When $k=1$ bounds are obtained [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08693.pdf); but what about in general?

Comment: The bound is actually simpler than it looks.  Extend your convex combinations to linear ones and then you obtain a fininte-dimensional (Banach) subspace of the Banach space of all finite signed Borel measures.  Since all norms are equivalent on finite-dimensional Banach spaces then you're done (after restricting back to the ball intersect the positive orthant).